# How to add bannerView on table view

Tags: ios

I want to add admob and

I have error
/Main.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: The bannerView outlet from the newsListTvc to the GADBannerView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Why?

Comment: Provide info about your storyboard and how are you trying to connect your objects with outlets.

Answer (score 1):

Cause the cell is reusable,so comes the error:

> Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Try the following options.

Opt1.

1. Implement a custom cell (name:xxx);
2. change the custom class to xxx in Identity Inspector and identifier to xxx in Attributes Inspector;
3. add the outlet to xxx;
4. use xxx in tableView.

Opt2.

add your bannerView programmatically in delegate method:

```
- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

Opt3.

change content type of tableView from Dynamic Prototypes(default) to Static Cells in Attributes Inspector, will remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the adview to the tableview as a cell, but as a header view